# How to bypass WhatsApp expiration

Tags: whatsapp.app

WhatsApp stopped running on my iPhone. It says it has expired and it requires me to update which I can't because I have an iPhone 4. It won’t run any versions of iOS newer than 7. Is there a workaround to bypass that restriction?

Comment: Highly unlikely - the app running on your iphone is probably a very basic a client which will need to use the same protocol as the WhatsApp servers; chances are the updates patch a security hole and make a chance to the protocol ergo the older app can no longer communicate with the rest of the network.

Comment: When people ask you to clarify a question, please edit the original question, don't post a new one :-)